# Why do these two blocks of code store different values?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, nullable

The setup:

`customObject` is an Entity Framework object and `customObject.is_required` is a nullable byte field representing a column in SQL Server that is `tinyint` and allows nulls.

`ddlIsRequired` is a dropdownlist with three items with the following values:

- `""` (for blank)
- `"1"` (for "yes")
- `"0"` (for "no")

Consider the following code:

```
customObj.is_required = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlIsRequired.SelectedValue), _
                          Nothing, _
                          ddlIsRequired.SelectedValue)
```

When executed, the above line of code stores 0 in the nullable byte field `customObj.is_required`

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlIsRequired.SelectedValue) Then
    customObj.is_required = Nothing
Else
    customObj.is_required = ddlIsRequired.SelectedValue
End If
```

When executed, the above block of code stores `Nothing` in `customObj.is_required` which is what I would have expected the inline-if to have done, yet the inline-if seems to treat the `nullable byte` field as though it is not nullable and instead stores the default value for any number (a zero).

Why is this?

Comment: By the way, what is the type of the `SelectedValue` property?  Is that an `Object` or a `String` property?

Comment: SelectedValue always returns a string.

Comment: Yeah, but what's the type of the property?

Comment: Via object browser: 
"Public Overridable Property SelectedValue as String": Summary:
Gets the value of the selected item in the list control, or selects the item in the list control that contains the specified value.

Return Values:
The value of the selected item in the list control. The default is an empty string ("").

Exceptions:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The selected value is not in the list of available values and view state or other state has been loaded (a postback has been performed). For more information, see the Remarks section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is the the `If` function must return a value with a given type. The compiler decides what type to return by looking at the two expressions for the return values (the 2nd and 3rd arguments). In your case, one value is `Nothing` and the other is a String. The compiler decides that the simplest type that can contain either `Nothing` or a String is a String. If the value selected is `Nothing` it is converted to a String ("") and if you have `Option Strict Off` (which is a bad idea), the String "" is converted to 0 when you assign it to a Byte?.

If you want to do it in a single statement, you will have to make it clear that the returned expression is a `Byte?`

```
customObj.is_required = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlIsRequired.SelectedValue), Nothing, CType(ddlIsRequired.SelectedValue, Byte?))
```

Comment: Aye, this makes sense now. A shame that the inline-if is so uptight about it. Question answered, thanks!

Comment: "Turn OptionStrict On" can not be said enough.

Comment: @MetalPhoenix You can force the `If` to return a `Byte?` if you like. I edited my answer to show how.

Comment: I was just making a comment about option strict, did you mean to address that to someone else, the OP perhaps?

Comment: Option Strict is indeed on. You never leave home without it. It shouldn't even be an option but, hey, it's VB.

Comment: @BradleyUffner My mistake. I was addressing MetalPhoenix and not you. I edited my comment.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Blackwood, the compiler automatically infers the return type of the ternary `If` operation by inspecting the types of the the last two arguments.  For instance:

```
Dim test As Object = If(True, "1", "2")
Console.WriteLine(test.GetType().Name) ' Outputs "String"
Dim test2 As Object = If(True, 1, 2)
Console.WriteLine(test.GetType().Name) ' Outputs "Int32"
```

In your case, the first value is `Nothing`, so the compiler cannot use it to infer the return type.  It then looks at the second value and sees that it is a `String` (as you stated in the comments above, the `SelectedValue` property is declared as a `String` property).  Therefore, the return type of the ternary operation is going to be `String`.

So, when it returns `Nothing`, it's returning it as a `String` type which is then converted to a nullable byte.  In other words, in long form, it's doing this:

```
Dim input As String = ddlIsRequired.SelectedValue
Dim stringOutput As String = Nothing
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) Then
    stringOutput = Nothing
Else
    stringOutput = input
End If
Dim output As Byte? = CType(output, Byte?)
customObj.is_required = output
```

And, since in VB `CType("", Byte?)` returns 0, that's what you get.  You can still use the ternary `If` operator, as long as you coerce it to the correct type:

```
customObj.is_required = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlIsRequired.SelectedValue), Nothing, CType(ddlIsRequired.SelectedValue, Byte?))
```

Which, in long-form, looks like this:

```
Dim input As String = ddlIsRequired.SelectedValue
Dim inputNullableByte As Byte? = CType(input, Byte?)
Dim output As Byte? = Nothing
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) Then
    output = Nothing
Else
    output = inputNullableByte
End If
customObj.is_required = output
```

As stated by others, by turning `Option Strict On`, the compiler will force you to coerce the input type that way or else it won't compile:

```
Option Strict On
' ...
Dim output As Byte? = If(True, Nothing, "1") ' Compiler error BC30512 Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Byte?'
```

Whereas:

```
Option Strict Off
' ...
Dim output As Byte? = If(True, Nothing, "1") ' Works and output gets set to 0
```